# How to initialise a char pointer and then create a string with it using sprintf

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I am creating a function which outputs the current system time in a certain format.

```
char *get_time() {
    char *current_time;
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm *timeinfo;

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    sprintf(current_time, "[%d/%d %d:%d] # ", timeinfo->tm_mday, timeinfo->tm_mon + 1, timeinfo->tm_hour, timeinfo->tm_min);

    return current_time;
}
```

`char *current_time` needs to be initialised before it is used in `sprintf()`. How can I do this?

Comment: It needs to be *allocated* before it is initialized.

Comment: You can use an array instead of a pointer, or you can call `malloc` to allocate storage for the pointer.

Comment: @TomKarzes ok, and how do I know exactly how much memory to allocate to it?

Comment: @CornOnTheKob you know the max length the sprintf string can return, plus a trailing null.

Comment: You need to conservatively estimate the longest possible string, and allocate enough space for it (and for the terminating null byte).

Comment: @CornOnTheKob: `"[:/ ] # "` gives 8 + 2 for day + 2 for month + 4 for year + 2 for hours + 2 for minutes = 19  + 1 for the `0`-terminator = 20.

Comment: @alk Perhaps 0 for year as it is not used.

Comment: @Chux Ups, thanks ... :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C99, *compound literals* offer a nifty solution for memory allocation.  The return value from `get_time()` is valid until the end of the block

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define GET_TIME_N 17
#define GET_TIME()  get_time((char[GET_TIME_N]) { ""}, GET_TIME_N)

char *get_time(char *current_time, size_t n) {
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm *timeinfo;
  time(&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
  snprintf(current_time, n, "[%d/%d %d:%d] # ", timeinfo->tm_mday,
          timeinfo->tm_mon + 1, timeinfo->tm_hour, timeinfo->tm_min);
  return current_time;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", GET_TIME(), GET_TIME(), GET_TIME());
}
```

Output

```
[27/3 12:33] # 
[27/3 12:33] # 
[27/3 12:33] #
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the amount of characters which would go into the target string cannot be determined `snprintf()` allows to calculate the necessary size by an addtional "fake" call.

From the C11 draft:

> ```
> int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n, const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```
>
> The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written
>   had n been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative
>   value if an encoding error occurred.

Example:

```
char * unknown_sized_string(const char * str)
{
  char * buffer = NULL;

  int size = snprintf(buffer, 0, 
    "I do not known how long this will be: %s", str);

  if (0 <= size)
  {
    buffer = malloc(size + 1);

    if (NULL != buffer)
    {
      snprintf(buffer, size,
        "I do not known how long this will be: %s", str);
    }
  }

  return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char *current_time = (char *) malloc(17)` allocates sufficient memory for a maximum sized `current_time` as well as the null terminator.

Comment: Yes. but as it was malloc'ed, it has to be freed by caller once used. The alternative would be to use a static char array (`static char current_time[17];`) that would be reused on each call. This latter solution is inherently not thread safe.

Comment: No need, no recommendation to cast here.